# How to handle tabbing for accessibility with a textarea that uses the tab button?

Tags: html, accessibility

I have a webpage that includes a `<textarea>` that uses JavaScript in order to utilize keyboard inputs like the `tab` key in order to indent lines, etc, just like a normal word processor or text editor.

When ensuring my webpage is accessible for screen readers, how does one handle the tab key in this situation? The user can tab around the webpage just fine but when they tab into the `textarea` they cannot tab out of it because the tab key is being used in the textarea for a different purpose.

What is the best solution to ensure that screen readers don't have an issue with this?

Answer (score 23):

Great question and thanks for considering accessibility.  This problem is not only for screen reader users but others that have mobility problems and can't use a mouse and rely solely on the keyboard for input.

The issue you're trying to prevent is [WCAG 2.1.2 No Keyboard Trap](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/keyboard-operation-trapping.html).

Using the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to allow indentation of text is a natural thing to provide for textareas.  One way around the problem is to allow <kbd>esc</kbd> to get you out of "edit mode" so that the <kbd>tab</kbd> key can now naturally move the focus to the next object.

I'm guessing you have a keyboard event handler that calls `preventDefault()` for <kbd>tab</kbd>.  If the user presses <kbd>esc</kbd>, change the way you're handling tab by letting it bubble up naturally (ie, don't call `preventDefault()`).  To go back into "edit mode", the user can press <kbd>enter</kbd> or they can tab off the textarea then tab back to it (ie, go into "edit mode" onfocus).

One key point of WCAG 2.1.2 is

> if [tabbing off the object] requires more than unmodified arrow or tab keys or other standard exit methods, the user is advised of the method for moving focus away.

So if you use <kbd>esc</kbd>, you'll need some onscreen directions that tells the user to press <kbd>esc</kbd> then <kbd>tab</kbd> to move the focus off the object, and those directions should be associated with the `<textarea>` via [`aria-describedby`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-describedby) so that screen readers know about it.

```
<div id="foo">Press ESC then TAB to move the focus off the field</div>
<label for="stuff">Enter your info here</label>
<textarea id="stuff" aria-describedby="foo"></textarea>
```

Comment: Oh wow good call on using Escape to exit focus. That's definitely what I'm going to do since not using Tab for indentation is kind of not possible in my use case. In your example is it okay for `#foo` to be visually hidden so that only SR's can see it?

Comment: If you visually hide "foo" so only screen readers can hear it, how will sighted users know how to move their focus out of the textarea?  (If you accept this answer, make sure you select the gray checkmark under the vote up/down triangles)

Comment: Good point. I will try to think of a way to convey that message to sighted users as well.

Comment: The overall theory of this is great, but one note: the broad consensus seems to be that Ctrl-M should be the shortcut used to toggle this. A 'rich text editor' section discussing this was included in the ARIA practices spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-wai-aria-practices-20090224/#richtext), but later removed due to other issues. https://github.com/w3c/aria-practices/issues/88 has some background. Imo Esc is nice too, where it fits - personally I'm planning to support both.

Answer (score 1):

There can be couple of possible solutions.

1.Override the default behavior of `tab` for `textarea` (you can do change tabindex or focus change, when user hits tab).

2.You can provide a shortcut(key combination e.g `CTRL+M`) on your page to change the `TAB` behaviour.

Comment: you can do further reading here https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/39868/accessible-way-to-override-tab-key-in-textarea

Answer (score 0):

According to [UI Events / Keyboard Event Types / keydown](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-type-keydown)

> If the key is the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, the default action **MUST** be to shift the document focus from the currently focused element (if any) to the new focused element, as described in Focus Event Types

So, as long as your implementing this in a web browser, you must not use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key for indentation. Handling the <kbd>space bar</kbd> use on the beginning of lines to add the correct number of spaces (or a tab char), in combination with any other shortcut (to indent multiple lines for instance), is a good alternative.

Comment: The W3 doc is intended for user agents and defines the default behavior for a browser.  I agree that a browser's default behavior is for the TAB key to move to the next element.  But that doesn't mean a website can't override what TAB does.  Granted, that shouldn't happen very often, but allowing TAB to indent code if the `textarea` is a "code editor" is a common behavior.

Comment: @slugolicious The W3C doc means that the browser will move the focus from the element before dispatching the event (which can lead to go outside the current document). Considering that screenreaders may also override the default behaviour for the TAB key, authors should find a replacement for the TAB key when wanting to use it for indentation.